# Instead of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: integration

It is a traditional result that 
\[
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A}^{\infty} f_{n}(t) dt
= \int_{A}^{\infty} f(t) dt
\]
if $f_{n}(t) \to f(t)$ for each $t$ and there exists an integrable function $\phi(t)$ 
satisfying
\[
|f_{n}(t)| \leq \phi(t)
\]
for all sufficiently large $n$.

On the other hands, as a undergrad student, I remember reading
in a book by T.M. Apostol that
the uniform convergence of integrals can somehow replace
the domination condition; uniform convergence of improper
integrals is defined as follows; given $\epsilon > 0$,
there exists a $B$ such that whenever $B_{1}, B_{2} > B$,
\[
|\int_{B_{1}}^{B_{2}}f_{n}(t)dt | < \epsilon
\]
for all $n$.

Is my memory correct?

Comment: You forgot to put $f_n \to f$

Comment: For the dominated convergence theorem. Yes, I did.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly! If $f_n \to f$ uniformly and the improper integrals converge uniformly then $\int_A ^{\infty } f_n (t) dt \to \int_A ^{\infty } f (t) dt$ and the proof is very simple. You just have to split the integrals into those over $(A,B)$ and $(B,\infty )$.

Comment: Do we need $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly? I actually did not write it down (but a weaker one about integrals $\int f_{n}$ as a whole). In a book by Lang, when he tries to prove the analyticity of $F(s) = \int f(s, t) dt$, he only uses uniform convergence of improper integrals and some other condition on $f(s, t)$.

Comment: Uniform convergence is needed to show the convergence of integrals over $(A,B)

Answer (score 2):

Without uniform convergence of the improper integral, we have the counterexample $f_n(x) = x^{-1} \chi_{[1,n]}(x)$ where

$$\int_1^\infty f_n = \int_1^n x^{-1} \, dx = \log n$$

is convergent and $f_n(x) \to x^{-1}$ uniformly on $[1,\infty)$, but $x^{-1}$ is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

With the stronger condition of uniform convergence (both for the improper integrals and $f_n \to f$) we can be assured that $f$ is integrable on any closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ and that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} f_n  = \int_{a}^{b} f$$

We then can show that $\int_0^\infty f$ converges.  For any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $B$ (which may depend on $\epsilon$, but not on $n$) such that if $b_2 > b_1 > B$, then we have

$$\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f_n \right| \leqslant \epsilon$$

implying that the improper integral $\int_a^\infty f$ converges by the Cauchy criterion.

There exists $c$ (independent of $n$) such that

$$\left|\int_c^\infty f_n\right| , \, \left|\int_c ^\infty f\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

We also have

$$\left|\int_a^\infty f_n - \int_a^\infty f\right| \leqslant \left|\int_a^c f_n - \int_a^c f\right| + \left|\int_c^\infty f_n\right| + \left|\int_c ^\infty f\right| \\ \leqslant   \left|\int_a^c f_n - \int_a^c f\right|  + \frac{2\epsilon}{3}$$

Given the uniform convergence $f_n \to f$ on the bounded interval $[a,c]$ we can show that the first term on the RHS is less than $\epsilon/3$ for sufficiently large $n$ and conclude.

Comment: Only the uniform convergence $f_{n} \to f$ over each bounded interval $[a, c]$ is required beside the u.c. of improper integral over $n$'s?

Comment: @Mr.SnowRemover: That should be sufficient.

Comment: Are we using the u.c. $f_{n} \to f$ in the equality $|\int_{b_{1}}^{b_{2}} f| = \lim |\int_{b_{1}}^{b_{2}} f_{n} |$ as well?

Comment: @Mr.SnowRemover: Yes, if $\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f_n \to \int_{b_1}^{b_2} f$ by uniform convergence of $f_n \to f$, then $\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f_n\right| \to \left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f\right|$ because $\left| \,\left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f_n\right| - \left|\int_{b_1}^{b_2} f\right|\, \right| \leqslant \left| \int_{b_1}^{b_2} f_n - \int_{b_1}^{b_2} f \right|$ by the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for many answers.